# Scala: Oracle JDBC generic with Quill

Tags: scala, quill

I am trying to pass generalized class as parameter . If I give Case class and values then it is working fine . But , would like to make it generic.

```
class DB[T] {
  lazy val ctx = new OracleJdbcContext(SnakeCase, "ctx")

  import ctx._

  def insert(input: T) = {
    val q = quote {
      query[T].insert(lift(input))
    }
    ctx.run(q)

  }

}
```

I am getting errors saying::
 "Can't find an implicit `SchemaMeta` for type `T`
   Can't find Encoder for type 'T'. Note that Encoders are invariant"

But, If I give actual class name then it is going well.

```
case class Location(street:String,pinCode:Int)

class DB {
  lazy val ctx = new OracleJdbcContext(SnakeCase, "ctx")
  import ctx._
  val q = quote {
      query[Location].insert(Location("2ndcross",500001))
    }
    ctx.run(q)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `SchemaMeta[T]` in scope to be able to execute queries using this type. Dummy solution would be to demand it as parameter constraint (and so implicit class parameter) like this

```
class DB[T: SchemaMeta]
```

but this wouldn't work, because it's `ctx` who provides those instances.

I believe that you will need to follow examples shown here: https://getquill.io/#contexts-dependent-contexts
But even then what you want may not be achievable.

Imporant thing to understand when working with quill is that almost everything there is based on macros and if you abstract things away then there is not enough information for these macros to act. So you either need to duplicate code requiring macros or wrap the code that is meant to be generic in your own macro.